# Which files do I install for Font Awesome

Tags: font-awesome

Hello, 
I am working on adding Font Awesome to my website.

On the Font Awesome github page it says simply:

"Install FontAwesome.otf and visit the copy & paste page. Happy designing"

Please can someone advise me - do I need to install all those other files that come in the folder downloaded from github? Those other files being:
fontawesome-webfont.eot
fontawesome-webfont.svg
fontawesome-webfont.ttf
fontawesome-webfont.woff

Thank you

Answer (score 5):

Yes :) I would install all of them. They are font files for different browser support.

Comment: Thank you very much for the very speedy reply. Odd then that the site itself should give out wrong advise saying just to - Install FontAwesome.otf ...!

Comment: There is nothing **wrong** with installing just the FontAwesome.otf file but it would be smart of you to install all of them :)

Comment: Don't forget you can mark this as the accepted answer (if it is) by clicking its check mark...

Answer (score 0):

Upload the files to your website and use @font-face in CSS

http://www.font-face.com/

This ensures the most amount of users will be able to see your font.

Here's an example:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'myFont';
    src: url('includes/fonts/DejaVuSans-webfont.eot');
    src: url('includes/fonts/DejaVuSans-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('fonts/LDejaVuSans-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('includes/fonts/DejaVuSans-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('includes/fonts/DejaVuSans-webfont.svg#DejaVuSansBook') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}


body{ font-family: myFont, arial; }
```